# ngrx/store:subscribe works fine but async in template gives [object Object]

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

### What is the current behavior?

I am trying to get the observable of a custom type

```
export interface ConfigurationState {
  outlet_id: number;
  api_key: string;
}
```

in my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'retail-root',
  templateUrl: './root.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./root.component.scss']
})
export class RootComponent implements OnInit {
  public config$: Observable<ConfigurationState>;

  constructor(private store: Store<fromRoot.State>) {
    this.config$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getConfigState);
    this.config$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.config$);
    this.store.dispatch(new configActions.GetConfig());
  }

}
```

When I use like below

```
{{ config$ | async }}
```

It gives me `[object Object]` but if do subscribe, `this.config$.subscribe(data => console.log(data));` I get my object correct in console.

Can anyone helps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess {{ config$ | async }} calls the object's .toString() method, which outputs its type.
Let's say your 'data' has a 'name' attribute, you can do:

```
{{ (config$ | async).name }}
```

I guess you can, too, do this

```
{{ config$ | async | json }}
```

the [json pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe) stringifies the content of a json.

Other option is to set the output from async to a variable and use in the template

```
<div *ngIf="config$ | async as data">
  {{ data.name }}
  {{ data.someAttr }}
  {{ data.otherAttr }}
</div>
```

Comment: second ahead of me, was just about to post the same :]